# Debug a memory buildup when object instantiates parent class: how should I proceed?

Tags: python, memory-leaks

I have an object that I am instantiating in a loop, which leads to memory buildup.

```
for l in range(10):
    
    grido = RasterModelGrid((3000, 3000), 10)
    
    # Tracking memory
    snapshot = tracemalloc.take_snapshot()
    top_stats = snapshot.statistics('traceback')
    
    # pick the biggest memory block
    stat = top_stats[0]
    print("%s memory blocks: %.1f KiB" % (stat.count, stat.size / 1024))
    for line in stat.traceback.format():
        print(line)
    
    del grido
    
    # Tracking memory
    snapshot = tracemalloc.take_snapshot()
    top_stats = snapshot.statistics('traceback')
    
    # pick the biggest memory block
    stat = top_stats[0]
    print("%s memory blocks: %.1f KiB" % (stat.count, stat.size / 1024))
    for line in stat.traceback.format():
        print(line)
```

with the debug output being:

```
    2 memory blocks: 281156.3 KiB
  File "/home/aargenti/eclipse-workspace/landlab/test_memory_leak.py", line 13
    grido = RasterModelGrid((3000, 3000), 10)
  File "/home/aargenti/eclipse-workspace/landlab/landlab/grid/raster.py", line 238
    DualUniformRectilinearGraph.__init__(
  File "/home/aargenti/eclipse-workspace/landlab/landlab/graph/structured_quad/dual_structured_quad.py", line 187
    UniformRectilinearGraph.__init__(self, shape, spacing=spacing, origin=origin)
  File "/home/aargenti/eclipse-workspace/landlab/landlab/graph/structured_quad/structured_quad.py", line 654
    StructuredQuadGraphExtras.__init__(self, node_y_and_x, sort=sort)
  File "/home/aargenti/eclipse-workspace/landlab/landlab/graph/structured_quad/structured_quad.py", line 518
    links=StructuredQuadLayoutCython.nodes_at_link(self.shape),
  File "/home/aargenti/eclipse-workspace/landlab/landlab/graph/structured_quad/structured_quad.py", line 88
    nodes_at_link = np.empty((n_links, 2), dtype=int)
2 memory blocks: 281156.3 KiB
  File "/home/aargenti/eclipse-workspace/landlab/test_memory_leak.py", line 13
    grido = RasterModelGrid((3000, 3000), 10)
  File "/home/aargenti/eclipse-workspace/landlab/landlab/grid/raster.py", line 238
    DualUniformRectilinearGraph.__init__(
  File "/home/aargenti/eclipse-workspace/landlab/landlab/graph/structured_quad/dual_structured_quad.py", line 187
    UniformRectilinearGraph.__init__(self, shape, spacing=spacing, origin=origin)
  File "/home/aargenti/eclipse-workspace/landlab/landlab/graph/structured_quad/structured_quad.py", line 654
    StructuredQuadGraphExtras.__init__(self, node_y_and_x, sort=sort)
  File "/home/aargenti/eclipse-workspace/landlab/landlab/graph/structured_quad/structured_quad.py", line 518
    links=StructuredQuadLayoutCython.nodes_at_link(self.shape),
  File "/home/aargenti/eclipse-workspace/landlab/landlab/graph/structured_quad/structured_quad.py", line 88
    nodes_at_link = np.empty((n_links, 2), dtype=int)
4 memory blocks: 562312.7 KiB
  File "/home/aargenti/eclipse-workspace/landlab/test_memory_leak.py", line 13
    grido = RasterModelGrid((3000, 3000), 10)
  File "/home/aargenti/eclipse-workspace/landlab/landlab/grid/raster.py", line 238
    DualUniformRectilinearGraph.__init__(
  File "/home/aargenti/eclipse-workspace/landlab/landlab/graph/structured_quad/dual_structured_quad.py", line 187
    UniformRectilinearGraph.__init__(self, shape, spacing=spacing, origin=origin)
  File "/home/aargenti/eclipse-workspace/landlab/landlab/graph/structured_quad/structured_quad.py", line 654
    StructuredQuadGraphExtras.__init__(self, node_y_and_x, sort=sort)
  File "/home/aargenti/eclipse-workspace/landlab/landlab/graph/structured_quad/structured_quad.py", line 518
    links=StructuredQuadLayoutCython.nodes_at_link(self.shape),
  File "/home/aargenti/eclipse-workspace/landlab/landlab/graph/structured_quad/structured_quad.py", line 88
    nodes_at_link = np.empty((n_links, 2), dtype=int)
4 memory blocks: 562312.7 KiB
  File "/home/aargenti/eclipse-workspace/landlab/test_memory_leak.py", line 13
    grido = RasterModelGrid((3000, 3000), 10)
  File "/home/aargenti/eclipse-workspace/landlab/landlab/grid/raster.py", line 238
    DualUniformRectilinearGraph.__init__(
  File "/home/aargenti/eclipse-workspace/landlab/landlab/graph/structured_quad/dual_structured_quad.py", line 187
    UniformRectilinearGraph.__init__(self, shape, spacing=spacing, origin=origin)
  File "/home/aargenti/eclipse-workspace/landlab/landlab/graph/structured_quad/structured_quad.py", line 654
    StructuredQuadGraphExtras.__init__(self, node_y_and_x, sort=sort)
  File "/home/aargenti/eclipse-workspace/landlab/landlab/graph/structured_quad/structured_quad.py", line 518
    links=StructuredQuadLayoutCython.nodes_at_link(self.shape),
  File "/home/aargenti/eclipse-workspace/landlab/landlab/graph/structured_quad/structured_quad.py", line 88
    nodes_at_link = np.empty((n_links, 2), dtype=int)
```

But when instead I instantiate the parent class directly with:

```
    grido = DualUniformRectilinearGraph((3000, 3000), 10)
```

instead of:

```
    grido = RasterModelGrid((3000, 3000), 10)
```

I don't have this memory problem:

```
2 memory blocks: 281156.3 KiB
  File "/home/aargenti/eclipse-workspace/landlab/test_memory_leak.py", line 16
    grido = DualUniformRectilinearGraph((3000, 3000), 10)
  File "/home/aargenti/eclipse-workspace/landlab/landlab/graph/structured_quad/dual_structured_quad.py", line 187
    UniformRectilinearGraph.__init__(self, shape, spacing=spacing, origin=origin)
  File "/home/aargenti/eclipse-workspace/landlab/landlab/graph/structured_quad/structured_quad.py", line 654
    StructuredQuadGraphExtras.__init__(self, node_y_and_x, sort=sort)
  File "/home/aargenti/eclipse-workspace/landlab/landlab/graph/structured_quad/structured_quad.py", line 518
    links=StructuredQuadLayoutCython.nodes_at_link(self.shape),
  File "/home/aargenti/eclipse-workspace/landlab/landlab/graph/structured_quad/structured_quad.py", line 88
    nodes_at_link = np.empty((n_links, 2), dtype=int)
571 memory blocks: 74.2 KiB
  File "/home/aargenti/eclipse-workspace/landlab/test_memory_leak.py", line 20
    top_stats = snapshot.statistics('traceback')
  File "/home/aargenti/anaconda3/envs/landlab/lib/python3.10/tracemalloc.py", line 533
    grouped = self._group_by(key_type, cumulative)
  File "/home/aargenti/anaconda3/envs/landlab/lib/python3.10/tracemalloc.py", line 498
    traceback = Traceback(frames)
  File "/home/aargenti/anaconda3/envs/landlab/lib/python3.10/tracemalloc.py", line 193
    self._frames = tuple(reversed(frames))
```

The initialization occurs with this code:

```
class RasterModelGrid(
    DiagonalsMixIn, DualUniformRectilinearGraph, ModelGrid, RasterModelGridPlotter
):

    def __init__(
        self,
        shape,
        xy_spacing=1.0,
        xy_of_lower_left=(0.0, 0.0),
        xy_of_reference=(0.0, 0.0),
        xy_axis_name=("x", "y"),
        xy_axis_units="-",
        bc=None,
    ):
        shape = tuple(shape)
        xy_spacing = np.asfarray(np.broadcast_to(xy_spacing, 2))
        self._xy_of_lower_left = tuple(np.asfarray(xy_of_lower_left))

        if shape[0] <= 0 or shape[1] <= 0:
            raise ValueError("number of rows and columns must be positive")

        DualUniformRectilinearGraph.__init__(
            self, shape, spacing=xy_spacing[::-1], origin=self.xy_of_lower_left[::-1]
        )
        ModelGrid.__init__(
            self,
            xy_axis_name=xy_axis_name,
            xy_axis_units=xy_axis_units,
            xy_of_reference=xy_of_reference,
        )

        self._node_status = np.full(
            self.number_of_nodes, NodeStatus.CORE, dtype=np.uint8
        )
        self._node_status[self.perimeter_nodes] = NodeStatus.FIXED_VALUE

        if bc is None:
            bc = {"right": "open", "top": "open", "left": "open", "bottom": "open"}

        if "closed" in bc.values():
            self.set_closed_boundaries_at_grid_edges(*grid_edge_is_closed_from_dict(bc))

        self.looped_node_properties = {}

        # List of looped neighbor cells (all 8 neighbors) for
        # given *cell ids* can be created if requested by the user.
        self._looped_cell_neighbor_list = None

        # List of second ring looped neighbor cells (all 16 neighbors) for
        # given *cell ids* can be created if requested by the user.
        self._looped_second_ring_cell_neighbor_list_created = False
```

Why is there this memory buildup when instantiating the child object?
I know this is not a minimal working code, but this is not my code, and I am not familiar with it. If you cannot tell what is going wrong, what would you recommend I test to see where the problem is coming from?

Comment: Are you able to run this program on Linux?

Comment: Yes, I'm using Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you are running on Ubuntu, I'd recommend using [chap](https://github.com/vmware/chap/graphs).

In your specific case, given that you are seeing memory buildup but not necessarily a crash, you should gather a live core for your process as follows:

```
echo 0x37 > /proc/pid-of-your-process/coredump_filter
gcore pid-of-your-process

chap core-file-just-created
```

When you reach the chap prompt, try:

```
describe used %ContainerPythonObject /redirectSuffix containers
```

That will create a file called core-file-name.containers.  You can search in that file for the **RasterModelGrid** and you will likely find many of them and it is very likely that each one is involved in some sort of cycle.  Given the address of a python allocation, you can understand how it is anchored by doing something like this from the chap prompt:

```
describe allocation address-you-just-found \
   /extend %ContainerPythonObject<- \
   /extend %PyDictKeysObject<- \
   /extend %PyDictValuesArray<- \
   /extend %PythonListItems<- \
   /skipUnfavoredReferences true \
   /commentExtensions true \
   /redirectSuffix RasterModelGridExplanation
```

If you look at the resulting file carefully, this should allow you to understand why that particular **RasterModelGridExplanation** is still in memory, where it is either still reachable or it is simply involved in a cycle and hasn't yet been garbage collected.